# Datacontext not available in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have the following grid:

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="CandiesDataGrid" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Candies}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCandy}">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CandySelectedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" Header="{l:LocText Candy_Prop1}" Binding="{Binding CandyInfo.Name}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="IsConfirmed" Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource CandyCheckBox}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsConfirmed, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Margin="-75 0 0 0"
                        Command="{Binding IsConfirmedCommand}">

                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My property uses the `OnPropertyChanged`. Not only it does not change the value of `IsConfirmed` but also does not executes the `ICommand` `IsConfirmedCommand`.

I searched on the internet and it seems `DataGridTemplateColumn` loses the `ItemSource` of the `datagrid`.

I did try to put `RelativeSource` in after the `mode=TwoWay` on my checkbox but it does not work.

Is there any way to have access to the ItemSource in my TemplateColumn?

EDIT:

```
//Properties
public ObservableCollection<Candy> Candies{ get; } = new ObservableCollection<Candy>();

public Candy SelectedCandy { get { return _selectedCandy; } set { SetProperty(ref _selectedCandy, value); } } //SetProperty acts as OnPropertyChanged

private Candy _selectedCandy;

//Constructor:
        public CandyClass()
        {
            IsConfirmedCommand = new DelegateCommand(IsConfirmedCommand_Execute);
        }

//Method
        private void IsConfirmedCommand_Execute()
        {
            //Doing something
        }
```

Comment: please show definitions of your view models

Comment: In the CellTemplate, the datacontext will be the *row*, a `Candy` instance. That's the point of a grid. To bind to  a property of the "parent" viewmodel that owns the Candies collection, you'll need a binding that goes back up the visual tree and locates the command on the DataContext of the DataGrid: `Command="{Binding DataContext.IsConfirmedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"` What is `IsConfirmed` a property of?

Comment: *"I did try to put RelativeSource in after the mode=TwoWay on my checkbox"* -- please don't say you "tried something" without telling us **what you tried**. RelativeSource isn't a magic spell that just makes things work via pony sparkles, and if the pony sparkles fail you toss it in the bin. You have to understand what it does and use it correctly. We can help you with that.

Comment: Maybe I did try it in the wrong way, is it possible that you make an aswer in how to use RelativeSource and what is it that solves the issue? IsConfirmed is a property of Candy and is a bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your CellTemplate, the DataContext is the DataGrid row, whatever that may be (`Candy` in this case). So by default, that `Candy` instance will be the `Source` property of any Binding in that DataTemplate. That's where the binding will look for the property named in the Path (`IsConfirmed` and `IsConfirmedCommand`, in this case).

That's what you want: You've got more than one row in the grid, and the row is what you care about in a cell, usually. That or the field: But very often a cell template will want to look at more than one field, so they give you the whole row.

But in this case, you want to go back up and grab something off the parent viewmodel. Viewmodels have no natural parent/child hierarchy, though you could give them one if you wanted: Candy could have a `Parent` property that had reference to the viewmodel that owns the `Candies` collection. If you did, you could bind like this:

```
Command="{Binding Parent.IsConfirmed}"
```

But that's not common practice. I don't know if it's a particularly great idea or not.

One reason we don't need to do that is we can tell the binding to use a different source instead. UI elements *do* have a natural parent/child hierarchy, and bindings can navigate it. If you’re doing things right, your parent viewmodel will be the DataContext of something up there somewhere.

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.IsConfirmed, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}
```

"Walk the UI tree upwards until you find a DataGrid. That's your source. Now, once you have a source, find the source object's DataContext property, if any. If it's got a DataContext, take the value of DataContext and look on that object for some property called IsConfirmed."

DataGrid has a DataContext property. Since your binding to `Candies` worked, we know that DataContext must be your class that has a `Candies` property. You assure me that class has `IsConfirmed` as well.

Hence:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox 
        Style="{StaticResource CandyCheckBox}"
        IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsConfirmed, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
        Margin="-75 0 0 0"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.IsConfirmedCommand,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
        />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Great, Now the command is working, what it does not seem to work is the IsChecked for some reason. I did put a break point in my IsConfirmed property but never goes to the set property.

Comment: Either `IsConfirmed` is called something else, or it's a property of a different class than `IsConfirmedCommand`. That's the property you didn't include in your question. If one of those bindings works, the other will work -- **provided the source property is actually there**. Check in the VS Output pane for binding errors. Add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` for a large amount of very detailed diagnostics. Just remember not to leave it there; it's expensive.