Not able to show bind Value in ui
Not able to show combo box value in ui which i was get in api.
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="132" Header="Status" Tag="Status">
 <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
             <ComboBox x:Name="cbx_Status" FontSize="10" MinHeight="29" Width="140" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="0" TabIndex="12"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"
                 SelectedValue="{Binding StatusDesc, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       KeyDown="cbx_Status_KeyDown" GettingFocus="cbx_Status_GettingFocus">

                 <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 -8 0 0"/>
                         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
                         <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                         <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                         <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                         <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False"/>
                     </Style>
                 </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
             </ComboBox>
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
 </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>

How does your grid's DataContext look like? You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616220/datacontext-not-available-in-datagridtemplatecolumn too.

It might be easier to help with more code around the DataGrid, its ItemsSource and StatusList.

Also try to remove code and leave just the minimal code that reproduces the issue.

To make the UI automatically updated when you Binding in ItemsSource you need to use ObservableCollection
public ObservableCollection<object> StatusList { get; } = new();


Already using observable collection. when i was click and select item and click another cell or column then its disappeared.
